# Trying to run a .dtsx package from .net with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have similar code for vb and .net which runs my SSIS package just fine. The problem is the c# code and .net does not run my .dtsx package. I get all sorts of errors in cluding not being able to find the file on my desktop. I tried remotely running the package and locally. Is it my code. I am not sure what to do next.
I do have all the correct references.

```
//    public class clsSSIS1
 //   {
  //      public static void RunDTSX()
   //     {
   //         string pkgLocation;
   //         pkgLocation = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\otmxm1\\Desktop\\LoadBeaPayroll\\LoadBeaPayroll\\bin\\package.dtsx";

  //              Application app = new Application();
  //              Package package = null;               
   //             Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null,true);
                //Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\Documents and Settings\otmxm1\Desktop\LoadBeaPayroll\LoadBeaPayroll\bin\package.dtsx", null);
  //              DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();
                //Console.WriteLine (result.ToString);
  //              Console.ReadKey();

 //           }
//        }
//    }
```

Comment: could you edit your post and format the code to something readable, please.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just execute the

```
dtexec.exe -f package.dtsx /conf ConfigurationIfYouGotOne
```

using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(xxx)`?

Or if the the SSIS is deployed to a SQL Server, you can execute it with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example I found:

1. Start the Visual Studio development environment, and create a new application in your preferred development language. This example uses a console application; however you can also run a package from a Windows Forms application, an ASP.NET Web form or Web service, or a Windows service.
2. On the Project menu, click Add Reference and add a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll. Click OK.
3. Use the Visual Basic Imports statement or the C# using statement to import the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime namespace.
4. Add the following code in the main routine. The completed console application should look like the following example.

---

```
  string pkgLocation;
  Package pkg;
  Application app;
  DTSExecResult pkgResults;

  pkgLocation =
    @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Samples\Integration Services" +
    @"\Package Samples\CalculatedColumns Sample\CalculatedColumns\CalculatedColumns.dtsx";
  app = new Application();
  pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
  pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

  Console.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx